# Does it make sense to put everything in a subclass of QApplication?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In my plugin-based architecture, the plugins must have access to all core components of the application, e.g. the main window, the settingswidget, the settings, the tray icon and several global immutable variables.

Since the application is a global singleton it is straight forward to subclass it and make all those components members of the application. This way I can 1. easily access them from everywhere 2. I can facade their API for the plugins 3. it feels natural that the components are members of the "app".

However reading the lessons on SO about singletons and globals it feels like bad design, but otherwise I'd have to implement a core facade and pass it around, which feels like bad design as well and is definitively less straight forward.

Comment: Feel free to look at the Qt Creator code base: it solves exactly the problem you're facing. It's all plugin-based, and the plugins do use each other.

Comment: I have. Although it is pretty popular, it is not that well designed, to say the least.

Comment: I updated the question since it seems like I was misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

Your description looks like a [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). That is indeed the sign of a potentially bad design.

Depending on what your plugins actually do, things like [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) may be a solution. Instead of giving access to the resources, make your objects suscribe to a mediator and let it make the connections to the resources.

Take also a look to [Inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to take the distinction between IS A and HAS A (inheritance vs. containment) seriously in this case.

A plug-in isn't a QApplication. It uses a QApplication. I don't see any reason to make it a subclass. Just give it a pointer or reference to QApplication.

This is one of the things the observer pattern does for you, subjects (QApplication) have references to their observers (Plugin). You also can use this in a symmetric way.

But using the observer pattern isn't always necessary. Main thing is your Plugins have a reference or pointer to the QApplication instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it helps but it seems singleton classes are sometimes used to access them from the outside.
In KDE they seem to be refereed to as Conltroler, and seem to be used over Plugin-Boundarys. (KDE is QT based, so i assume a KDEPlugin is similar to a QT one.)
PS: This is in answer form, because i don't have "Comment everywhere".